# WP8 emulator stopped working

Tags: hyper-v, windows-phone-8

Ok so I was working fine with the WP8 emulator but suddenly after going into Hyper-V manager it stopped working, didn't make any change and even deleted the virtual machine to be created again on debug but no luck

I have tried with the various emulator images but none of them seems to work anymore, event viewer shows no errors on Hyper-V.

What I have noticed is that the virtual machine starts in Hyper-V goes to Windows logo, then hangs for a few minutes in a black screen and turns off afterwards automatically, tried starting it without debuging, directly from hyper-v but nothing works, should I reinstall the SDK? seems to me this is not install related since it worked before

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the connect forums, I don't know if it will fix your problem:

I had issues with the emulator and tried several things, including the below solutions and on a few occasions couldn't figure out what the problem was so I restored a previous image since that was quick.

From Discussion "RTW - Can't debug - IP Address Issue"

> 1. Uninstall the SDK
> 2. Uninstall and reinstall the virtual switches using:
> 3. C:> netcfg –u vms_pp
> 4. C:> netcfg –c p –i vms_pp
> 5. Reboot
> 6. Reinstall the SDK

From Discussion "Emulator and wireless adapter issues"

> Problem solved! Hyper-V uses same MAC address for guest VMs (virtual
>   machine) and Host. If the router configured to give the host always
>   same ip address it will conflict with the emulator. Solution - on the
>   router remove the host from known PCs and let it give you some new ip
>   address (not fixed). After you start the emulator it will get the
>   correct ip address from router. Router will show you two PCs (host and
>   vm) with the same MAC, but different ip addresses.

Comment: Thanks. I think that makes sense, I'm in a corporate network and seems to give the same ip but I don't think I will have access to the router config, maybe I can change the emulator ip manually?

Comment: As expected it works in my home, so this should be an ip issue, I think is easier to change my pc ip once in the office, I'll report how that works

Comment: Well it looks I got stuck again, it does not work at my home again, I think the only solution right now is to uninstall the SDK, the vms and reinstall the SDK

Comment: Haven't tried uninstalling again but with a fresh install in another computer and the same networks the emulator works good

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled, I can say this is a solution but still haven't found what is the root cause of the emulator to stop working, my guess is somehow the vm image gets corrupted at some point, right now I'm trying to figure out why I can't see the start screen, just the App list screen uhm

Comment: Even if the image gets corrupted, restarting it is suppose to "reset" it back to the way it was.  That's if you don't get the IPv4 error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the instances in Hyper-V, and then run `XdeCleanup`.

Comment: I did it but didn't work, like in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149509/windows-phone-8-emulator-error-something-happened-while-creating-a-switch