# Windows Phone 8 Emulator can't start

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator

I have installed windows phone 8 SDK and tried running a simple app. When I try to run the app in emulator the emulator does not get internet connection. It displays an error message saying "You don't have permission to modify internal Hyper-V network adapter settings required to run the emulator". Im sure my login has admin permissions.

Can anyone tell me how to get it working. Thanks so much..

[image: first shot]

[image: second shot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this problem, I combined steps from this **2 posts**:

[Windows Phone 8 emulator error - Something happened while creating a switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149509/windows-phone-8-emulator-error-something-happened-while-creating-a-switch#_=_) 
and

http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/petevickers/archive/2012/11/01/troubleshooting-windows-phone-8-emulator-problems.aspx.

I first ran **XdeCleanup.exe** from *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.0*.
Then, I entered Hyper-V Manager and created a new Virtual Switch (as described in the articles) - in *Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections* it was created under the name **vEthernet (Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)**.

I was also facing the problem that my internet connection uses user configured IP settings. 
The emulator created another virtual switch, called **vEthernet (Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet Virtual Switch)** , which resulted in no internet connection for my computer (**Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet** is the name of my real network adapter to which the created virtual switch was connected).

So, what I did was set the IP address and the other information of the virtual switch **vEthernet (Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet Virtual Switch)** to the information for the real adapter, which solved the internet connection problem of my PC.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

You should try out the following things -

1. Run VS 2012 as **administrator**.
2. Open **Hyper-V Manager** and check the **Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch** from **Virtual Switch Manager**. Remove the emulator switch and start a new instance of the emulator.
3. If your host computer has a WLAN connection, you should check whether it is running fine or not.
4. If your host computer is in a dedicated network, you can do a wired tethering and create a peer to peer network with another computer. Enable unrestricted internet in one of the systems, share the connection with the other computer, the emulator running in that, will also get the shared internet.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks bro, I use windows 8.1 with visual studio 2013, so no error anymore.

Comment: I get the error "Failed while removing virtual Ethernet switch".

Comment: VS 2013 - point 1 did the trick. Running once as admin, then it works also with normal mode.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with Windows Phone 10 Preview Emulator under Visual Studio 2015 RC. The solution was:

1. Go to "Turn Windows features on or off"
2. Remove Hyper-V
3. Restart
4. Reinstall Hyper-V
5. Restart
6. You're a go :)

Comment: This solution helped me with VS 2015 RC and WP 8.1 U1 emulator

Answer (score 1):

1 - Go to Hyper-V Manager
2- Remove emulators Windows Phone 8.
3 - precionas Virtual Switch Manager
4 - Eliminate Internal Windows Phone Emulator.
5 - Restart
6- Start the emulator again.

I hope that is helpful.