# How to resolve this Windows Phone 8 Emulator error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm working on a **windows phone 8 app** in **VS 2012** .and when configuring I got this error.Searched some options for this but didn't work.if somebody knows the correct process  to overcome this problem please let me know..Thnaks

**Error** - `the windows phone emulator wasn't able to create the virtual machine.Something happend while creating a swithch : Xde`

**Snapshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have Hyper-V for running Emulator in Windows 8. Hyper-v is virtualization solution.You can install this by,

Control Panel >> Programs and Features >> on the left panel Click on “Turn Windows features on or off”.
Select  “Hyper-V” option and Click on OK.

To fix this spefic issue,
Open the Hyper-V Manager from the start menu, and open the Virtual Switch Manager. Remove any existing switches, and try make a new virtual switch with a connection type set to internal.

You might need to run XdeCleanup.exe afterwards
Restarting the machine also will help

[Solution for Xde Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149509/windows-phone-8-emulator-error-something-happened-while-creating-a-switch)