# Can't connect to my windows phone emulator on visual studio 2013

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, hyper-v

I build an easy App in visual studio 2013, creating it through the windows phone project. The main thing is that it's supposed to fetch data from a API of my choice and write to an XML- document. It worked code-wise but depending on what network I was using(Wireless), It gave me either and error or it worked. It worked if I compiled with my phone as the network supplier, but not on my wireless at home or the schools network.

The error I recived everytime was "the thread has exited with code 259"

I googled for some solutions, and I guessed (Not really sure it was the answer I was looking for) that the error was due because of the phone emulator "takes" my PC's IP adress or network.

They told me to just remove my phone emulator on Hyper-V manager and then just re-start my emulation and it should work.

After this was done, all hell broke lose, cause now, visual studio can't even connect to the emulator.It creates a new phone emulator in hyper-v, but can't connect to it. When I try to compile the app I created it says "Trying to connect to "WVGA 512MB" or if I choose another "WVGA 720". It does this for about 3-5 min and then it says "An error occured. Would you like to continue?"

Now I have no idea what to do. I've googled for almost 2 days and I am at lost. I've un-installed, re-installed, repaired all my visual studio but nothing helps. I am using visual studio premium 2013 if that helps..

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is due to the network issues, as you said the emulator takes the default PC's IP address. But normally after removing the emulator from the Hyper-V Manager and when you try to restart it, it should work.

If none of them works try removing all the `Virtual Switches` from your Virtual Switch Manager which is within the Hyper-V Manager. Then create a new `Internal` type of a Virtual Switch and restart your machine. Then try launching the emulator.

For more look into these:

[Windows Phone 8 emulator can't connect to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159947/)

[Windows Phone 8 emulator error - Something happened while creating a switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149509/)

[(WP8) Emulator (XDE) Troubleshooting Tips](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b06cc9f2-aa5e-4cb3-9df1-0c273e1dfd68/wp8-emulator-xde-troubleshooting-tips?forum=wptools)