# Windows Phone Emulator is unable to create internal network switch

Tags: windows-phone-8

I received this message when running the emulator:

> [Window Title] Windows Phone Emulator
>
> [Content] Windows Phone Emulator is unable to create the internal
>   network switch:
>
> Something happened while creating a switch: Failed while creating
>   virtual Ethernet switch.
>
> Switch create failed, name = '186E24AD-DE28-4C32-A93D-FF494B43B772',
>   friendly name = 'Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch': %%3758096900
>   (0xE0000204).
>
> [Close]

Why it gives this error, and how could I fix it?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149509/windows-phone-8-emulator-error-something-happened-while-creating-a-switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Oracle Virtual Box and Windows Phone Emulator works fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1.Go into Hyper V Manager. 
2.Go into Virtual Switch Manager. 
3.Create a new virtual switch called 'Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch'. 
4.Set it's connection type to Internal.
5.Now launch the emulator. It should work.
(May be a reboot will be needed)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this operation gives an error:[Window Title]
Virtual Switch Manager for ADAVIDOAIEI

[Main Instruction]
Error applying Virtual Switch Properties changes

[Content]
Failed while creating virtual Ethernet switch.

[Expanded Information]
Switch create failed, name = '7EFC1D6C-7D33-4998-945F-67DA1D78028E', friendly name = 'Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch': %%3758096900 (0xE0000204).

[^] Hide details  [Close]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after digging for couple of hours finally I did this:

1. Go to programs and features and turn of the hyper-v through "turn windows features on or off" then restart the computer and turn it on and restart the computer again to have a fresh hyper-v.
2. Run cmd where Xde.exe is installed (usually in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0") and run command "Xde.exe -v sdcard.vhd"
3. Run Xde.exe as administrator (you will get an error)
4. Run visual studio and try to open emulator by deploy a  project.

I don't know witch one fixed the problem but the problem goes away.