# Visual Studio Android Emulator stuck when creating virtual machine

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, vs-android

Ok so my Visual Studio Android emulators stopped working this morning. First I was was receiving a networking error and so I tried to delete and re-create them, but the creation keeps getting stuck on "Copy .vhd files and creating virtual machine". The last time I tried it I let it sit on that step for over half an hour, and that was after trying first this [Visual studio (2015) emulator for android not working - XDE.exe - Exit Code 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613607/visual-studio-2015-emulator-for-android-not-working-xde-exe-exit-code-3) then this [Visual studio android emulator will not start fully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547546/visual-studio-android-emulator-will-not-start-fully)

Oh and I completely uninstalled and re-installed Visual Studio Emulator for Android.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got a VM to download and execute after reinstalling Hyper-V (un-check Hyper-V from Windows Features, reboot, re-check it, reboot). I've gone through many of the referenced cleanup steps many times prior to trying that, though I did perform a repair of the Visual Studio Emulator for Android and deleted all of the device profiles just before reinstalling Hyper-V.