# Is it possible to use Windows Phone 8 Emulator outside of current PC

Tags: hyper-v, windows-phone-8

I've installed Windows 8 as guest in Hyper-V VM. Tried to launch WP8 emulator and failed.

So I have a question: Is it possible to reuse WP8 emulators in host system to develop inside virtual machine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to create the virtual machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148828/unable-to-create-the-virtual-machine)

Comment: Trying to find a workaround when we don't have a SLAT-capable machine is terrible. I noticed that WP8 Emulator was working smoothly inside a Windows 2012 VM hosted by Windows 8. But it crashed every 30 minutes. So I decided to install Windows Server 2012 on a real partition. To realize that it's exactly like running it in Windows 8 without SLAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know - it's not possible, you can only debug on real devices or emulators running on the same machine. Also the machine for running emulators must run on bare metal, not in virtualized environment because of some requiredm CPU features like SLAT.

Comment: Too bad... Have played a little with configurations inside VM with no luck. My plans to develop from work on my home PC without interrupting home users are ruined :(

Comment: You should be able to connect to your home PC with WP8 SDK and emulators running on Hyper-V using remote desktop, but you must run the Hyper-V on bare metal.

Comment: The emulator can run in a Windows 2012 VM on a non-SLAT machine, but with a regular HAL_INITIALIZATION_FAILED blue screen of death.