# WP8 SDK on a virtual machine?

Tags: sdk, windows-8, ram, windows-phone-8, virtual-pc

I have a HP EliteBook 8560p with 4GB ram and a 2,5Ghz i5-2450M processor running windows 7.

My question is: will I be able to run the WP8 SDK on a virtual mashine running W8 that i give 3GB ram to or will it be to slow? The system requirements for the SDK says 4GB minimum. Unfortunately this is my schoolcomputer so I am not allowed to install W8 as the operating system, that's why I want to use a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to MDumitru answer, you should install virtual box not VMware. Windows Phone 8 SDK requires [hardware Hyper-V support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148828/unable-to-create-the-virtual-machine)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148828/unable-to-create-the-virtual-machine). You can follow [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator) article while installing VMware and WP8 sdk inside it.

Comment: It won't be too slow but the difference between the speed will be clearly visible while restarting the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to run W8 and WP8 SDK on a virtual machine, but you'll likely have a very slow experience.

Comment: Ok, it´s probably just to try it out and see how it works then.