# Can't run Windows Phone Emulator on Windows 10 with Parallels 11

Tags: windows, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator, parallels

I can't run a Windows Phone Emulator on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with Parallels 11 on my MacBook.

I've already tried to change the number of processors to 1 in Parallels and Hyper-V, but nothing seems to work.

This is the error I'm getting:
[image: Printscreen from error]

### **SOLVED**

I had to enable nested virtualization' in Parallels by going to 'Hardware settings' -> 'CPU & Memory' -> 'Advanced settings' -> check 'Enable nested virtualization'

Comment: I believe the Windows Phone Emulator requires SLAT ([Second Level Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Level_Address_Translation)), hardware assisted virtualization, and hardware DEP support. I could not verify, whether or not Parallels 11 supports all of the above, or has to be configured to enable those hardware virtualization features. See a similar question asking about the Windows Phone 8 Emulator: [Unable to create the virtual machine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13148828/1889329).