# Windows phone 8 SDK - This computer does not support hardware virtualization, which means Windows Phone Emulator 8.0 can't run on this PC

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, windows-phone-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to create the virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148828/unable-to-create-the-virtual-machine)

Warning during installation of WP8 SDK: "This computer does not support hardware virtualization, which means Windows Phone Emulator 8.0 can't run on this PC."

Environment:
Windows 8 Enterprise 64, on a VirtualBox VM, 4G RAM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must run your Windows 8 instance on bare metal, not in a virtual machine, to be able to test WP8 apps on WP8 emulator.
I've described more requirements for the WP8 development here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13145586/574062

Comment: This answer is plain wrong now (I'm sure it was probably correct when it was written). Unfortunately because the question is marked as duplicate the correct answer cannot be provided as an answer.  The Duplicate question does answer somewhat correctly so go read that. And/Or check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/588008/Creating-a-Virtual-Windows-Phone-8-Development-Env

Answer (score 1):

This issue is that you cannot have a box inside of a box and expect to have the same exact coin in each box, that is to say that you cannot run a virtual machine in a virtual machine and have them both using hardware virtualization extensions to speedup processing, I't looks like your running in a virtual machine which is your issue. To use the virtual phone you must install windows 8 on your base pc, or another windows 8 compatible pc. This is the only way to use the software due to the way it was coded.

Comment: This article describes how to do exactly that in VMware: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator