# Windows phone 7 app on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I have seen there is support for windows phone 7 app on windows phone 8. I have developed some apps on windows phone 7 and I want to run it on windows phone 8 emulator to test my app. Is there any way for doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, just open your Windows Phone 7 Solution in Visual Studio 2012 with Windows Phone 8 SDK installed, select as target Windows Phone 8 emulator and run your app. You can even choose between various screen resolutions.
The minimal system requirements for running Windows Phone 8 emulator are here:
[What does it take to run the Windows Phone 8 emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145464/what-does-it-take-to-run-the-windows-8-phone-emulator/13145586#13145586)

Answer (score 1):

Once you open your WP7 app in VS 2012 with WP SDK 8.0 with target platform for WP8 you can't use this project anymore as WP7 project.
If you want to continue to develop in new environment in VS 2012 you need to use Target platform: WP 7.1

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the XAP Deployment tool so that you don't have to open the project in Visual Studio.