# How to Upgrade Windows Phone Emulator only Emulator 7 to Emulator 8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, upgrade, windows-phone-8

How to Upgrade Windows Phone Emulator only Emulator 7 to Emulator 8

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Windows Phone 7 SDK. But i want to upgrade only Windows Phone 7 Emulator to Windows Phone 8 Emulator or i will have to Install WP* SDK.

Comment: You cannot upgrade emulator. You will have to install WP8 SDK (which is only supported in Windows 8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use Windows Phone 8 Emulator, you have to install the Windows Phone 8 SDK. System requirements of this SDK are here:
[What does it take to run the Windows Phone 8 emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145464/what-does-it-take-to-run-the-windows-8-phone-emulator/13145586#13145586)