# How to install the Windows Phone 8 SDK in Windows 8 Release Preview

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I have the Windows 8 Release Preview (I know, Windows 8 official is out, just haven't ponied up the money to get the official version yet..), and I was wondering if there was a way to install the Windows Phone 8 SDK onto the Release Preview version of Windows 8?
Has anyone had any experience with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't install whe WP8 SDK on pre-release of Windows 8.
The WP8 SDK and emulator requirements are here:
[What does it take to run the Windows Phone 8 emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145464/what-does-it-take-to-run-the-windows-8-phone-emulator/13145586#13145586)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That answers the question. I guess I have to buy Windows 8 sometime soon heh.

Comment: yes, and for emulator to work, your processor must support SLAT.