# Didn't find windows phone 8 emulator

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I installed Visual Studio 2012 and Windows Phone 8 SDK successfully. I created a new phone app and trying to run but it doesn't show me any emulators in Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your PC satisfies the system requirements for running the emulator:

- Windows 8 Pro edition or greater
- A processor that supports Second
  Level Address Translation (SLAT)

> If your computer meets the hardware and operating system requirements,
>   but does not meet the requirements for the Windows Phone 8 Emulator,
>   the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 will install and run. However, the Windows
>   Phone 8 Emulator will not function and you will not be able to deploy
>   or test apps on the Windows Phone 8 Emulator.

[Source](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much @Olivier's answer. Also, make sure you have Hyper-V enabled on your computer.

In lieu of this, There's a very nice tool on codeplex that pretty much checks if [your computer is able to start hyper-v and the windows phone emulator](http://slatstatuscheck.codeplex.com/).

If that passes, you'll want to follow [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in order to get hyper-v set up. Specifically the two enabling sections.

There was a post a little while back on what is required specifically here on stack overflow. It can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145464/what-does-it-take-to-run-the-windows-phone-8-emulator/13145586#13145586)